# If $b>0$ then find the number of values of'a' for which domain and range of $f\left(x\right)=\sqrt{ax^{2}+bx}$ are equal.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Q:

> If $b>0$ then find the number of values of'a' for which domain and range of $f\left(x\right)=\sqrt{ax^{2}+bx}$  are equal.

**My approach:**

Since we have a square root, $$ax^{2}+bx\ge0\to x\left(ax+b\right)\ge0$$
If $a>0$ then domain is: $$x \in \ \left(-\infty,-\frac{b}{a}\right] \cup \ \left[0,\infty\right)$$

If $a<0$ then domain is:

$$[0,-\frac{b}{a}]$$

If $a=0$ then domain is: $$x\ge0$$

But I don't know how to proceed further with the main question. Any hints or suggestions are welcome.

Answer:

> 2 values of a are possible.

Comment: The $a$ values that satisfy this condition are $-4$ and $0$.  Graphing both of these functions should give you an idea why.

Comment: To each other!  That's a common construction in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a < 0$ the domain you pointed out is wrong , the right one is $[0,-\frac{b}{a}]$.

One value is $a = 0$  because then $f(x) = \sqrt{bx}$ which has range $[0,\infty]$.

For $a > 0$ there can't be no value having domain = range because your domain has always negative values inside while range, because of the presence of the square root, needs to contain just positive values.

So the second value has $a < 0$, now you can see that $f(0) = f(-\frac{b}{a}) = 0$ and that is the minimum value of the range , consequently the maximum is attained inside the interval so you can just use a derivative test to find which one is it :

$$f'(x) = 0 \implies \frac{2ax+b}{2 \sqrt{ax^2+bx}} = 0 \implies  x = -\frac{b}{2a}$$

and so the maximum is $f(-\frac{b}{2a}) = b\sqrt{\frac{1}{4a}-\frac{1}{2a}}$, but then to have domain = range you need that

$$b\sqrt{\frac{1}{4a}-\frac{1}{2a}} = -\frac{b}{a} \implies a =-4$$

Comment: So you mean for a>0, there are still negative values in domain while range is positive. I got this part. But I still couldn't find how to get -4

Comment: @Vega did you find it at the end?

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot figure it out :(

Comment: see now, I updated!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your  question as wanting to find if and when  $\space x=y.\quad $ I thought I had it immediately until I noticed the rquirement: $\space b>0$
$$
f(x)=y=\sqrt{ax^{2}+bx}\\
ax^{2}+bx-y^2=0\\
$$
by inspection we can see first solutions and  then generalize the pattern
$$
\quad x=y=0\qquad a,b\in\mathbb{Z^+}\\
\quad x=y=-1\quad a=2,\space b=1\\
\quad x=y=-2\quad a=2,\space b=2\\
\quad x=y=-3\quad a=2,\space b=3\\
\quad x=y=-4\quad a=2,\space b=4\\
\vdots \\
\quad x=y=-n\quad a=2,\space b=n$$